# SQL add column with default values to Dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of Clients, i need to add another column with periods for each client. How can i do it?

```
ClientID
0001
0002
0003

PeriodID
01/2017
02/2017
03/2017
```

I need to get this like result:

```
ClientID PeriodID
0001 01/2017
0001 02/2017
0001 03/2017

0002 01/2017
0002 02/2017
0002 03/2017

0003 01/2017
0003 02/2017
0003 03/2017
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a cross join:

```
select c.ClientID, p.PeriodId
from clients c cross join
     periods p;
```

Comment: It's really hard to guess, if he want to add acolumn or just need this outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use cross join

```
Select ClientId, PeriodId from yourclienttable cross join yourperiodtable
```

Comment: What is the diffrence between your answer and Gordon answer?